# Reading endpoint url of a file/folder under WebContent

Tags: java, servlets

Iam using this below code to get my endpoint url

```
   URL url=getServletContext().getResource("/PdfToHtml");
    System.out.println(url);
```

The output displayed as

```
  **jndi:/ipaddress/LoginValidation/PdfToHtml**
```

But i need the actual output to be displayed as complete url like this

```
  **http://ipaddress:8080/LoginValidation/PdfToHtml**
```

Please let me know what should i do in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try like this..

```
    String url=getServletContext().getResource("/index101.jsp").getPath();
    url=url.replace("localhost", "localhost:8080");//if you need port otherwise comment it
    System.out.println(url);
```

Comment: Still its not working, again its displaying the path like D:// but i need in endpoint url format, thankx

Comment: What exactly is showing to you can you just show ... ?

Comment: Still i used your code to access the files inside of my WebContent folder, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got answer with many efforts and all your helps,

String fullcontextpath=request.getScheme()+"://"+InetAddress.getHostName().getHostAddress()+":"+request.getServerPort()+"/"+request.getContextPath();

It returns me the url path, getScheme --> returns http or https . Inet address returns the ip address, serverport returns the server port number , finally the curent prog\ject context.

Thank you all for your kind help.